# How to find and change string in Perl using quotemeta

Tags: regex, string, perl

my string = `<bibliomixed>Williams, G. L. (2004) The Higher Education Market in the United Kingdom. In P. Teixeira, B. Jongbloed, D. Dill and A. Amaral, <emphasis role="italic">Markets in Higher Education: Rhetoric or Reality?</emphasis> Dordrecht, the Netherlands: Kluwer.</bibliomixed>`

I want to find this string in HTML Document and change. but I use `quotemeta` function while searching the above string in HTML document, which gives the following string after came through from quotemeta function :

`\<bibliomixed\>Williams\,\ G\.\ L\.\ \(2004\)\ The\ Higher\ Education\ Market\ in\ the\ United\ Kingdom\.\ In\ P\.\ Teixeira\,\ B\.\ Jongbloed\,\ D\.\ Dill\ and\ A\.\ Amaral\,\ \<emphasis\ role\=\"italic\"\>Markets\ in\ Higher\ Education\:\ Rhetoric\ or\ Reality\?\<\/emphasis\>\ Dordrecht\,\ the\ Netherlands\:\ Kluwer\.\<\/bibliomixed\>`

so when searching with this string was not finding in perl and also tried to find the string with notepad++ with regular expression option, thats also not working

Kindly any one suggest any solution for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code and mentioned html document would be helpful.

Comment: How do you *search* for the string? If there is no variation, you can use `index` and no quoting is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = q|<bibliomixed>Williams, G. L. (2004) The Higher Education Market in the United Kingdom. In P. Teixeira, B. Jongbloed, D. Dill and A. Amaral, <emphasis role="italic">Markets in Higher Education: Rhetoric or Reality?</emphasis> Dordrecht, the Netherlands: Kluwer.</bibliomixed>|;
my $html = q|<html><head><body>something.....nowmy string <bibliomixed>Williams, G. L. (2004) The Higher Education Market in the United Kingdom. In P. Teixeira, B. Jongbloed, D. Dill and A. Amaral, <emphasis role="italic">Markets in Higher Education: Rhetoric or Reality?</emphasis> Dordrecht, the Netherlands: Kluwer.</bibliomixed> now some extra text|;
my $result = index $html, $string;
print "$result";
```

If result is not -1, it means it matched.